# Trouble with the most basic of basic jQuery questions

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am struggling to fathom why the following fiddle won't work? Just trying to add a class!

Just starting out.

Thanks, and please don't downgrade me... I know its basic.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="box">a</li>
    <li class="box">b</li>
    <li class="box">c</li>
    <li class="box">d</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}

li .hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').addClass('hover');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JGqAX/

Comment: You don't need js for this, you can use the rule 'li:hover'

Comment: 3 practically identical answers. :P

Comment: @chrisvdp but the OP isn't trying to do anything on `hover` just adding a class with name `hover`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your CSS the declaration:

> li .hover

Targets an element with class `.hover` inside `li` like:

```
<li>  <p class="hover">Select this element</p>  </li>
```

You need:

> li.hover

An element `li` with class `hover`. Will match:

```
<li class="hover">Make me blue</li>
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/JGqAX/1/

Comment: Grrr... I knew it would be something silly... there's me staring at the script!

Comment: @PeteNorris :P most common when you expect some JS error then !Bam is a CSS mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake not in JS, but in CSS: an extra space between **li** and **.hover**

```
li.hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JGqAX/2/

Answer (score 2):

It's not jQuery, it's your css selector, which should be:

```
li.hover
```

which selects "`li` elements with the class `hover`", instead of:

```
li .hover
```

which selects "elements with the class `hover` that are descendants of `li` elements"